# Security for user created apps

Tags: javascript, python, security, dsl

I have a chat site. It's a pretty standard IRC style chat that works within your browser. I'd like to allow users to create and upload apps that can enhance the chat experience. One example of an app would be a trivia game. Users would use this by issuing chat messages like `/addtriviaquestion "foo"`.

The technical problem I'm stuck on is how I can execute a user's code while preventing it from being malicious.

My site is built in django/python. I'd love to use javascript for these apps. For example, the trivia module could work like so:

```
register.command('/addtriviaquestion', function() {foo;});
register.command('/answerquestion', function() {foo;});
```

Anybody have an idea how I can get python to execute this jailed and untrusted javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use phantomjs http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/ that executes javascript to get the html generated by javascript, like in this post http://inka-labs.com/es/blog/2012/05/24/get-executed-html/ and then clean the code with BeautifulSoup, the problem is that the result is not going to be dynamic HTML anymore. Another idea would be to have the uploaded code running on an iframe with a different domain, in that case the default browser iframe security blocks any attempt of the iframe script to modify its parent's elements.

Comment: Hey Jose! TY for the suggestions. I was thinking of a different approach, using http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/. The only thing is, I haven't been able to get it to compile on OSX or Ubuntu yet.